# What is the meaning of: little gel software wonks

Tags: meaning

A sentence from the novel *Leviathan Wakes*:

> Surveillance equipment, communication arrays, serious-as-fuck servers with their own little gel software wonks already built in.

I am trying to translate that expression: *"little gel software wonks"*.

I cannot make sense of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for literary interpretation/analysis.

Comment: @Drew What is purpose of this forum at all? Isn't it about English language and Usage?

Comment: Feel free to post your question about the purpose of EL&U and its relevance to literary interpretation [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Zingam There's a useful introduction to the site [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I assume *their own little gel* is a somewhat sexist reference akin to *their own "**girl Friday** software wonks*, but I have to say I've not come across this usage of ***software wonks*** before either (presumably it's a somewhat metaphorical usage referring to anthropomorphised "little helpers" in the server software, I dunno).

Answer (score 4):

This is science fiction, right? They appear to be describing some fictional technology, so I can't give you definitive answer, but I can speculate and give you a plausible answer.

"Gel" would suggest some sort of biological computer.

"Gel software" would be software that runs on a gel computer.

A [wonk](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wonk) is "a person who studies a subject or issue in an excessively assiduous and thorough manner". So in this case I would guess that a wonk is some sort of analyzer or an artificial intelligence that does some kind of analysis.